# Complement of the Image is the Image of the Complement

Tags: functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Given a continuous linear map $T:E\to F$ where $E,F$ are normed vector spaces,
I am wondering about the trivial question whether for any subset $U\subset E$, it holds or not:
$$T(U^c)=T(U)^c$$
I could make sense of this just under the assumption that $T$ is *surjective*, but I am not sure if the following reasoning is correct:

- trivially we have that $E=U\oplus U^c$, therefore $T(E)=T(U)\oplus T(U^c)$ by linearity of $T$.
- by surjectivity we have that $T(E)=F$, hence $F=T(U)\oplus T(U^c)$ $\underline{which \ implies}$:
  $$T(U^c)=T(U)^c\ $$

I am not really sure about the underlined implication.
Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried a $2\times 2$ matrix $T$ where the columns are not orthogonal?

Comment: Filippo: Sorry but I prefer to wait that you post [your own answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1112595) and accept it one minute later.

Answer (score 0):

This is false: since $T(U)$ for any subspace $U$ is itself a linear subspace, it contains the zero element. This implies that the complement of a subspace cannot contain zero.

Comment: what you said is wrong. The complement of a vector space is a vector space, and indeed it must contains the *zero*-element. In fact, given a vector space $X$ one has that:
$$X\cap X^c=\{0\}$$

Comment: @Filippo There is some confusion here between complement (normally denoted as $X^c$ and defined as the set of elements that do not belong to $X$) and [orthogonal complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement) usually denoted as $X^{\bot}$.

Comment: @drhab Let $G ⊂ E$ be a closed subspace of a Banach space $E$. A subspace
$L ⊂ E$ is said to be a *topological complement* or simply a *complement* of $G$ if:
- (i) $L$ is closed,
- (ii) $G∩L=\{0\}$ and $G+L=E$.

Comment: then please clarify your question: I have never seen the notation $U^c$ to be used for complement subspace. Moreover, the notation suggests that the complement is uniquely defined.