# Bound for Integrator Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compactness, compact-operators

Let $E = L^p(0,1)$ with $1 ≤ p < ∞$. Given $u ∈ E$, set

$$Tu(x):=\int_0^x u(t)dt$$

Prove that $T$ is compact on $E$.

I would like to use Ascoli-Arzela', but I need to prove:

$$|T u(x) − T u(y)| ≤ |x − y|^{1/p′}||u||_p\ \ (1)\ .$$

I have problems proving (1):

$$|T u(x) − T u(y)|=|\int_x^y u(t)dt\ |\leq\int_x^y |u(t)|dt$$

but I do not see how to continue to get to the desired result.

Moreover, applying Ascoli-Arzela' to $T(B_E)$ (where $B_E$ is the unit ball in $E$), we get that the closure of $T(B_E)$ is compact in $C[0,1]$. Why does this imply that $T(B_E)$ has compact closure in $L^p(0,1)$ as well? 
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Holder's inequality: $$\int_x^y |u(t)| \, dt \le \left( \int_x^y 1 \, dt \right)^{1/p'} \left( \int_x^y |u(t)|^p \, dt \right)^{1/p} \le |x-y|^{1/p'} \|u\|_p.$$

Comment: applying Ascoli-Arzela' to $T(B_E)$ (where $B_E$ is the unit ball in $E$), we get that the closure of $T(B_E)$ is compact in $C[0,1]$. Why does this imply that $T(B_E)$ has compact closure in $L^p(0,1)$ as well?

Comment: Filippo: Sorry but I prefer to wait that you post [your own answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1112595) and accept it one minute later.